# responding to a read request from bluetooth le in ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect and read the received value from a smart bluetooth in ionic app. It's nrf8001 .

I'm using bluetoothle plugin which is [here](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle)

I can successfully connect to central and add the services. but the problem is that , when I send data from central to my phone , the required event is not calling!

should I advertise the peripheral or sth else?

Comment: "when I send data from central to my phone" If you use the nRF8001, the phone _is_ the central. And if you connected successfully you don't advertise anymore.

Comment: @EirikM thank you sir, but now help me on this, when nrf8001 sends data to my phone , how should I receive its request. I'm using initializePeripheral callback to get the read request event , but nothing happens after sending data from phone

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the framework you use, but I see a few required steps: 1. Connect to the peripheral - 2. Discover services (and characteristics) - 3. At this point you can read and write from the phone. If you want something to happen when the nRF8001 sends data you could use the subscribe function.